# RealmList with @Parcelize annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, parcelable, parceler

I'm trying to use the new `@Parcelize` annotation added with Kotlin 1.1.4 with a Realm objet containing a RealmList attribute.

```
@Parcelize
@RealmClass
open class Garage(
        var name: String? = null,
        var cars: RealmList<Car> = RealmList()
) : Parcelable, RealmModel
```

As `RealmList` is not supported by the annotation and assuming that `@Parcelize` is there specially to avoid creating methods what would be the solution to support `RealmList` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***EDIT:***

Using the power of Type Parcelers and `@WriteWith` annotation, it is possible to create a RealmList type parceler that can handle this scenario for you:

With the following code:

```
fun <T> Parcel.readRealmList(clazz: Class<T>): RealmList<T>?
    where T : RealmModel,
          T : Parcelable = when {
    readInt() > 0 -> RealmList<T>().also { list ->
        repeat(readInt()) {
            list.add(readParcelable(clazz.classLoader))
        }
    }
    else -> null
}

fun <T> Parcel.writeRealmList(realmList: RealmList<T>?, clazz: Class<T>)
    where T : RealmModel,
          T : Parcelable {
    writeInt(when {
        realmList == null -> 0
        else -> 1
    })
    if (realmList != null) {
        writeInt(realmList.size)
        for (t in realmList) {
            writeParcelable(t, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

You can define an interface like this:

```
interface RealmListParceler<T>: Parceler<RealmList<T>?> where T: RealmModel, T: Parcelable {
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel): RealmList<T>? = parcel.readRealmList(clazz)

    override fun RealmList<T>?.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeRealmList(this, clazz)
    }

    val clazz : Class<T>
}
```

Where you'll need to create a specific parceler for the `RealmList<Car>` like this:

```
object CarRealmListParceler: RealmListParceler<Car> {
    override val clazz: Class<Car>
        get() = Car::class.java
}
```

but with that, now you can do the following:

```
@Parcelize
@RealmClass
open class Garage(
        var name: String? = null,
        var cars: @WriteWith<CarRealmListParceler> RealmList<Car> = RealmList()
) : Parcelable, RealmModel
```

And

```
@Parcelize
@RealmClass
open class Car(
    ..
): RealmModel, Parcelable {
    ...
}
```

This way you don't need to manually write the Parceler logic.

---

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

Following should work:

```
@Parcelize
open class Garage: RealmObject(), Parcelable {
    var name: String? = null
    var cars: RealmList<Car>? = null

    companion object : Parceler<Garage> {
        override fun Garage.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            parcel.writeNullableString(name)
            parcel.writeRealmList(cars)
        }

        override fun create(parcel: Parcel): Garage = Garage().apply {
            name = parcel.readNullableString()
            cars = parcel.readRealmList()
        }
    }
}
```

As long as you also add following extension functions:

```
inline fun <reified T> Parcel.writeRealmList(realmList: RealmList<T>?)
    where T : RealmModel,
          T : Parcelable {
    writeInt(when {
        realmList == null -> 0
        else -> 1
    })
    if (realmList != null) {
        writeInt(realmList.size)
        for (t in realmList) {
            writeParcelable(t, 0)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> Parcel.readRealmList(): RealmList<T>?
    where T : RealmModel,
          T : Parcelable = when {
    readInt() > 0 -> RealmList<T>().also { list ->
        repeat(readInt()) {
            list.add(readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader))
        }
    }
    else -> null
}
```

and also

```
fun Parcel.writeNullableString(string: String?) {
    writeInt(when {
        string == null -> 0
        else -> 1
    })
    if (string != null) {
        writeString(string)
    }
}

fun Parcel.readNullableString(): String? = when {
    readInt() > 0 -> readString()
    else -> null
}
```

Comment: Amazing, you're amazing ! I'm implementing it right now. I just have a question. We won't have access to `cars` or `name ` variables in the companion object. How to solve this ?

Comment: You do because Parceler gives you `Garage.write` and otherwise you are creating a new instance of it (i kinda had a copy paste error there a sec ago) --- but I just realized [I can probably also improve this answer a bit using a `Parceler<RealmList<T>>` with `@WriteWith<RealmListParceler>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) - assuming I can get its generic to work, anyways

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to make `object RealmListParceler<T>:` because `<T>` is not allowed on object, not sure if I can make it better then.

Comment: What I meant is your code won't compile because the variable `cars` in `parcel.writeRealmList(cars)` is not accessible within the companion object.

Comment: Yes it is accessible, because it is `Garage.write(`.

Comment: Oh sorry, did't saw it

Comment: Thanks a lot you're amazing. It's working like a charm !

Comment: @AlexandreNussbaumer thanks for accepted, however this way you need to write Parcelable implementation (albeit nicer). Can you try the edited answer if that also works (it's at the top)? I was tinkering with that for the past 20 mins and I think it should work too.

Comment: I really like your new cleaner implementation. Just added your code but it doesn't compile. Actually in your interface ´RealmListParceler<T>: Parceler<RealmList<T>?>´, ´RealmList<T>?´ is not within its bounds, it should be a ´Parcelable´ and for the ´@WriteWith´, it says PARCELABLE_TPYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED for ´@Parcelable´ do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Both `Car` and `Garage` must be Parcelable. Also, I had to make the `Parcel.write...` and `Parcel.read...` extension functions be top-level functions, along with the interface and the object. Also, there is no such thing as `@Parcelable`, it's `@Parcelize`..... But I've just added this into my test project for this `var parents: @WriteWith<PersonRealmListParceler> RealmList<Person> = RealmList()` and it works, so I think you are missing a `>` somewhere

Comment: So I tried out what I wrote and it worked, I can't tell from a distance what went wrong on your side :|

Comment: I implemented your logic again and it does work now, I don't know why it wasn't building before. Again, many thanks!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for this. I am using it but now am getting multiple errors in writeToParcel(Unknown Source:251). I think it's coming from a model using LinkingObjects. How do I exclude LinkingObjects from the parcel? I am using Kotlin Parcelize