# How to use Parcel.readTypedList() along with @Parcelize from kotlin-android-extensions?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm running into a problem with implementing Parcelable-based state persistence in a View. Namely, as I need to implement the methods of `BaseSavedState` like this:

```
class SavedState : BaseSavedState {
    lateinit var myList: ArrayList<MyParcelable>

    constructor(superState: Parcelable) : super(superState) {}

    private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : super(parcel) {
        val listSize = parcel.readInt()
        val list = ArrayList<MyParcelable>(listSize)
        this.myList = parcel.readTypedList(list, /* needs MyParcelable.CREATOR */ )
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
        out.writeInt(myList.size())
        out.writeTypedList(myList)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> = object : Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> {
            override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): SavedState {
                return SavedState(`in`)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<SavedState?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, as you can see, I can't seem to use `Parcel.readTypedList()` because it needs both the typed list, and the parcelable's `CREATOR` field!

Classes marked like:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyParcelable(val someData: String): Parcelable {
}
```

Do not have CREATORs, in fact, if you try to implement, it says:

> 'CREATOR' definition is not allowed. Use 'Parceler' companion object instead.

I do **not** want a Parceler companion object, I need a CREATOR!

I also kinda don't want to write the Parcelable implementation by hand, so I might just make it Serializable and be like "whatever".

---

Does anyone know by chance how you can use `Parcel.readTypedList()` with `@Parcelize`-annotated Kotlin data class?

Comment: Apparently this is a reported bug in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19853 and can be worked around with getting the generated CREATOR using reflection.  It's also known since a year ago, apparently, but nobody really seems to have cared about it. Well, `Serializable` it is in the meantime.

Comment: I might be able to do the same thing you need to do when you're parcelling RealmList: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455684/realmlist-with-parcelize-annotation/49456435?noredirect=1#comment88761626_49456435

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/fc013c6b9f5f3083d06385803ff687dc9a6ab4f0#

From Kotlin 1.6.21,
we can use **parcelableCreator**() from

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.parcelableCreator

val dataClass = TestDataClass("someValue")
val creator = parcelableCreator<TestDataClass>()
val parcel: Parcel? = null
parcel?.createTypedArrayList(creator) // Will compile
```

Answer (score 12):

It's a bug on the Parcelize plugin like you mentioned https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19853 and it can be solved by either reflection or actually, you can have a proxy class to java as you can access that `CREATOR` field in java without any problems.

I made a util **java** class for all creators and then made a kotlin extension referring to that creator

Java

```
@NonNull
public static Parcelable.Creator<Blah> getBlahCreator() {
    return Blah.CREATOR;
}
```

Kotlin

```
val Blah.Companion.CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Blah>
 get() = UtilClass.getBlahCreator()
```

And now I can access `Blah.CREATOR` anywhere! And those two classes that have all the creators and extensions could be just deleted later after the bug got fixed in the foreseeable future and it'll just work as expected without any edits in the other classes that use the `CREATOR`

This feels much better to me than the reflection solution! but either way, they are both disgusting and I hope this bug could be fixed soon enough!

Comment: I mean if you can access the creator field just like that then you can expose a Helper class in Java that has a single function which returns the CREATOR instance. I don't need to copy the object, I just need its creator :p I'll check this when I'm near a PC

Comment: Didn't even think of `val Blah.Companion.CREATOR`, I like it! Thanks!

Comment: What does the code inside the kotlin version of getBlahCreator() look like?

Comment: @AndrewKelly file named `UtilClass.java` with this content `class UtilClass {
@NonNull
public static Parcelable.Creator<Blah> getBlahCreator() {
    return Blah.CREATOR;
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

Upvoted for the question as I encounter the same problem in one of class, but its not visible as I am a new user.
I used the below alternative,(readArrayList)though it has are minor difference

```
readTypedList
arrayListOf<YourParcelableClass>().apply { parcel.readArrayList(YourParcelableClass::class.java.classLoader) }
```

Thanks for accepted solution but not sure why, even in java class file I am not able to read the CREATOR field.

Comment: Seems more suitable for a new question or a comment than an answer.