# How to make RealmList<String> Parcelable?

Tags: android, realm, parcelable

```
@Parcelize open class TestClass(
        @SerialName("title")   
        var title: String,
        @SerialName("list")   
        var list: RealmList<String>    
) : RealmObject() { ... }
```

How can I parcelize `"list"` variable in this implementation?
It says, that it's not possible to parcel this type of value even if I add `@RawValue`.
What's the alternative here? An example with explanation would be flawless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a RealmList parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619845/how-to-make-a-realmlist-parcelable)

Comment: @HemantParmar In given example, there's no `@Parcelize` as well as an example for primitive list type of String.

Comment: If you need to pass object between activity using `Intent`,1.Just pass id and then getObj by id, 2. Get Object from realm then pass un-managed that object, 3. Convert that object to Json and pass as `String`. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621950/1283715).

Comment: @KhaledLela I followed the "kotlin" example and I see some type of "Converter" classes that are made for custom object. In my case the type of list is String. Isn't there a way to avoid `Converter` classes like that as the type of my list is primitive and should/might be supported by Realm itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarly to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455684/realmlist-with-parcelize-annotation/49456435#49456435), you can do

```
fun Parcel.readStringRealmList(): RealmList<String>? = when {
    readInt() > 0 -> RealmList<String>().also { list ->
        repeat(readInt()) {
            list.add(readString())
        }
    }
    else -> null
}

fun Parcel.writeStringRealmList(realmList: RealmList<String>?) {
    writeInt(when {
        realmList == null -> 0
        else -> 1
    })
    if (realmList != null) {
        writeInt(realmList.size)
        for (t in realmList) {
            writeString(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
object StringRealmListParceler: Parceler<RealmList<String>?>  {
    override fun create(parcel: Parcel): RealmList<String>? = parcel.readStringRealmList()

    override fun RealmList<String>?.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeStringRealmList(this)
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
@Parcelize 
open class TestClass(
        @SerialName("title")   
        var title: String = "",
        @SerialName("list")   
        var list: @WriteWith<StringRealmListParceler> RealmList<String>? = null
) : RealmObject(), Parcelable { ... }
```