# How to parcel RealmList<String>?

Tags: android, realm

I've a list of strings that I want to parcelize and then put into Realm.

```
public class X extends RealmObject ... 

private @SerialName("ha") RealmList<String> list;

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int i) {
    //how to do this?  
}

private X(Parcel in) {
    ///how to do this?  
}
```

I'm not sure how can I `writeToParcel` and `readToParcel` RealmList?

Comment: have you tried setting write and read as a String array in parcel methods?

Comment: Well, it's different type. Writing array requires String values not whole RealmList<String>. This means I have to create some kind of method that does that for me, which looks like alot more like creating parcelize mechanism and storing RealmList<T> values, where T is object. I thought that there should be alot easier method of doing this, as they now support RealmList<String> as a primitive list. This should be a common situation. Maybe someone can share their solutions to this?

Comment: I was going to say https://stackoverflow.com/a/51840457/2413303 but that's Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any collection into Parcelable by writing out its size and then re-constructing it.

```
private @SerialName("ha") RealmList<String> list;

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int i) {
    out.writeInt(list != null ? 1 : 0);
    if(list != null) {
        out.writeInt(list.size());
        for(String item: list) {
            out.writeString(item);
        }
    }
}

private X(Parcel in) {
    boolean hasList = in.readInt() > 0;
    if(hasList) {
        int size = in.readInt();
        list = new RealmList<String>(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(in.readString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works good, but I get empty Array values in db, haha. I did not fully understand your code in K function. What's hasList? Should not I somehow read string array into my RealmList<String>?

Comment: That's to handle nullability, that's all. Managed RealmObject cannot have null RealmList, but it's there for sake of completion anyway. Not sure why you'd get empty values though.

Comment: How should I add this field in DbMigration? Variable is defined: 
        @SerialName("ha") var list: @WriteWith<StringRealmListParceler> RealmList<String>? = null
_____________


x.addField("fieldName", //whatType?);

Comment: `addRealmListField("fieldName", String::class.java)`